# CSS input over img

Tags: css

I am trying to make a search input bar and i dont want the text to go under the img [image: 1st]

I want it to automaticly be like this.[image: ddd] :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add:

```
input {text-indent: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 50px;

    /* Makes it not affect width */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

This makes it so it doesn't affect with width but still adds padding

Using the `text-indent` is practically the exact same, you still need the:

[Fiddle: text-indent](http://jsfiddle.net/UPN6v/6/)

[Fiddle: padding](http://jsfiddle.net/UPN6v/5/)

`UPDATE: Fixed Fiddle`